# How to read the bearing angle in postgis ST_Azimuth (geometry)

Tags: azimuth

I have calculated the bearing of two sets of points using the ST_Azimuth (geometry) function of Postgis.

I get values like

1.42985896479537
1.44293722688266
1.45994672393791
1.48436591051383
1.51617271196433
4.22987568535437
4.27561945155804

can anyone tell me how to make sense of them.
I am trying to locate points which are on right and which are on left side of other point set.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
select
   degrees(st_azimuth(geom,geom)) as your_column
   from
   your_table;
```